# Can I substitute and return the matched portion of parentheses without $+?

Tags: perl, substitution

The following piece of code *does* essentially what I want to achieve: it substitutes a portion of a variable and assigns a part of the substituted value to `$foo`:

```
my $value = "The foo is 42, but the bar is 12!";

my $foo = $+ if $value =~ s/foo is (\d+)//;

print "foo: $foo\n" if $foo;
print $value, "\n";
```

My question is if this is "the right way" to do that. Particularly, I am not so happy with `$foo = $+ if ... s/.../.../` construct and was wondering if there is a (what I feel) more elegant way to do this.

Comment: @DavidK-J:  `$+` is fine to use. Why do you think it will slow things down? Also, it is better to test the success of the substitution rather the definedness of `$1`.

Comment: Fine, I misread the intention. A better message to begin is "don't use uncommon perl punctuation vars"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's hard to know what sort of thing you're getting at, but here are some reason why *not* to write it that way.

You should *never* write something like

```
my $foo = $+ if $value =~ s/foo is (\d+)//
```

because the result is officially undefined. [`perldoc perlsyn`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Statement-Modifiers) has this to say

> **NOTE**: The behaviour of a `my`, `state`, or `our` modified with a statement modifier conditional or loop construct (for example, `my $x if ...`) is undefined. The value of the `my` variable may be `undef`, any previously assigned value, or possibly anything else. Don't rely on it.

Also, it is better to use the capture variable `$1` because it is more explicit, and because many people may not know what `$+` does. And it is more descriptive to test whether the substitution succeeded than if `$foo` is defined.

I would write something like this

```
my $value = "The foo is 42, but the bar is 12!";

if ( $value =~ s/foo is (\d+)// ) {
  my $foo = $1;
  print "foo: $foo\n";
}

print $value, "\n";
```

Answer (score -1):

If you assign a match expression with subexpressions to a list, the matches will be assigned to the list elements:

```
my $value = "The foo is 42, but the bar is 12!";

my ($foo) = $value =~ /foo is (\d+)/;
$value = $`.$';

print "foo: $foo\n" if $foo;
print "$value\n";
```

But apparently this doesn't work for substitutions, so you'll need to substitute separately.  I don't know how to assign and substitute at once.

Comment: This prints `foo: 1` not `foo: 42`.

Comment: Thanks - I should have checked prior to posting. I have corrected my answer.